# The No-letter cycle

Tags: c++, loops, visual-c++, while-loop, cin

Can you explain how does it work, especially `while (!(cin >> n) || (cin.peek() != '\n')` ?
If I input numbers(1,2,3..) it works.If I input letters (a,b,c,d),it says me to enter one more time.

```cpp
while (!(cin >> n) || (cin.peek() != '\n'))
{
  cin.clear();
  cin.ignore(256, '\n');
  cout << "enter n ";
}
```

Comment: Step through it with a debugger, try entering some different input, see what happens. If you want more help then please try to create a [mcve] to show us, or at least tell us what `n` is. Also please read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: which part specifically you do not understand? `cin >> n` ? conversion of `cin` to `bool` ? `peek` ? `||` ? Please try to be more specific, any further input from you helps to answer the question

Comment: I understand ,that if I inputs letters cycle begin working and says me to enter correct number

Comment: what does it do cin.peek() != '\n'

Comment: According to the cycle I enters the value

Comment: The `while` loop head basically says, in words, "loop until" (`cin` reads successfully into `n`, and the immediate next character is `'\n'`)

Comment: (cin.peek() != '\n') and what is the difference (cin.peek() == '\n')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first condition in the while loop

```
!(cin >> n)
```

checks whether the input was successful.

The second condition

```
(cin.peek() != '\n')
```

whether after the input the buffer contains the new line character '\n' that is whether the user pressed the Enter key.

For example if the buffer contains

```
123A\n
```

then if an object of an integral type is read then it can get the value `123` and the first condition will evaluate to true though as you see the input in general is invalid.

So this while loop excludes such a situation though if the user appends the input with a blank like

```
123_\n
```

where the underscore means a blank then this input also will be rejected. The only valid input is

```
123\n
```

That is the loop requires that the user entered a number without any additional symbols after the number and press the Enter key.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.